# Remove objects which has been repeated in two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, drop

I have a data frame like this:
[image]

and the dataset in the CSV file is [here](https://www.udrop.com/5Xsy/data.csv).

this data was extracted from the IMDb dataset.
but I have a problem, I could not be able to remove the actor's names which are repeated in the same row for example in row number 4 I want to drop 'Marie Gruber' in both name and actors column.
I tried to use to apply and all conditions but always code consider it the same.
like this code:

```
data[data['name'] != data['actors']]
```

Comment: You want to remove the repeated entry in a row, and then what would you like to put in the place of the removed entry?

Comment: Probably both strings are different and you have some extra spaces in one of them.

Comment: I want to drop those rows which have the same value like row 3 , 'Maria Gruber' are the same in both columns.

Comment: Try `data[data['name'].str.strip() != data['actors'].str.strip()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trere are traling spaces for `actors` column, so first remove them by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
data['actors'] = data['actors'].str.strip()
data[data['name'] != data['actors']]
```

Or use `skipinitialspace=True` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True)
data[data['name'] != data['actors']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.dataframe.drop` function.

```py
data.drop(data[data.apply(lambda x: x['name'] in x['actors'], axis = 1)].index)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work either.

Comment: It should work just fine now.